# How to skip new line in EOF?

Tags: c++, eof

My code

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "library_list.h"

    using namespace std;
    library_list::library_list(string filePath){

        ifstream library_read_file_pointer(filePath);
        string line_data_read_from_library_data_file;
        while (!library_read_file_pointer.eof()){
            getline(library_read_file_pointer, line_data_read_from_library_data_file);
            library_read l(line_data_read_from_library_data_file);//l is a library_read object that will parse
            lirary_data.push_back(l);//l content will save in vector(library data)

        }
        library_read_file_pointer.close();
    }
```

The problem is that `getline` is reading the new line as a data and my main program is showing last data two times how I can make `eof` or `getline` to ignore/don't read the new line.

Comment: Combine your `while` and `getline`: `while (std::getline(library_read_file_pointer, line_data_read_from_library_data_file)) { ...` You need to read *before* checking.

Comment: Where did you get the idea to name your variables like that from?

Comment: `while (!library_read_file_pointer.eof()){` agggggggghhhhhhhh

Comment: i don't get any of your suggestion plz  explain it more